# In HTML5 JavaScript, how do I read a BLOB field from an Sqlite database and use it as content in my web app?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, html, blob, webos

An example would be very helpful. I've been handed a Sqlite db with images in it and I have to get them, then use them in my webOS app (it just JavaScript :-))

I know how to get an sql record, but how do I use the BLOB data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any server-side scripts? If so, you can create a file (e.g. image.php) that fetches and outputs the BLOB data depending on the GET parameters. Then in your HTML, you would have `<img src="image.php?id=11" />`